# What word or phrase might a vegetarian culture use instead of "meatspace"?

Tags: language

I'm looking for a word or phrase that might be used in a vegetarian culture to denote the non-cyber "world", and that is not "meatspace" or "real life".

The best I've come up with so far is "fleshspace". Is there something better?

Comment: What does said culture call the stuff that animals are made of?  Consider that "meatspace" refers to the space occupied by humans, which are *almost* universally accepted as not a foodstuff.

Comment: Carbonville.
Fixed-law Land.
First World.
This is such an open-ended question, I’m voting to close it. It totally depends upon the culture you’re trying to convey in your story.

Comment: Unless vegetarians in your world believe people are made of vegetables, why would they need a different word? 'Meatspace' doesn't mean 'where all the meat we eat is'.

Comment: @Giter - People aren't made of meat. Meat is animal flesh that's eaten or prepared for eating. I know what meatspace "means". It contains a metaphor that references eating animal flesh.

Comment: Good question, @CortAmmon. That's where I was coming from with "fleshspace".

Comment: @SRM - It's not hugely "open-ended": I doubt I'll get more than 5 or 10 decent suggestions, they'll all be words or short phrases, and if this site's any good they'll each be supported with good succinct reasons. Thanks for the warm welcome though, posted within minutes of my asking.

Comment: That’s my job as site moderator — to close questions quickly before they get lots of attention. Questions like these are closed because they do not have right answers AND give no benefit to future askers of the same question (because their story constraints aren’t the same as yours). There’s a reason this is a standard Reason To Close. This is a common discussion with new users on this StackExchange.

Comment: @user66341 --- Greetings! You might want to take a look at the [tour] and [help] so you can understand what kinds of queries fit here and why folks think yours doesn't.  Also, you might consider that a(n average) human is about 40% meat.  Hence, "meatspace".  You might also consider describing this "vegetarian culture" somewhat in order to ward off the cries of "too opinion based!"

Answer (score 2):

**The Drudge**

It's the place of cooking, cleaning AKA drudgery.

Answer (score 0):

**Carnivorestuff**

One can also transform it into **carnivorestuff** is a great way to say foodstuff for meat eaters.